# dmesg shows 0 512-byte logical blocks

Tags: usb, hard-disk, io, dmesg, scsi

Last week I unfortunatly dropped by external HDD drive and it wouldn't spin up anymore. I got other backups, so I thoughed I opened it up so see whats wrong. The read/write head was stuck and damaged, without leaving traces on the disk.

I decided renew the read/write head with a donor HDD. The whole process was a success, the disk spins up but make "weird clicking" noises, as it couldn't align on the disk.

dmesg outputs the following:

```
scsi host6: usb-storage 5-1.2.4.4:1.0
[1821218.413643] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     asmedia  ASMT1053         0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[1821218.413865] scsi 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[1821218.419210] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Spinning up disk...
[1821219.436465] ................ready
[1821234.799407] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[1821234.799992] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[1821234.799995] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[1821234.800992] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[1821234.819785] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk
```

I'm confused about the line

```
[sdg] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
```

Same happens if I use the original USB controller, but now it shows me I got 2 TB instead of 500 GB:

```
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[1822017.465381] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1822054.928729] usb 5-1.2.4.4: new high-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[1822055.030814] usb 5-1.2.4.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2300, bcdDevice= 1.30
[1822055.030818] usb 5-1.2.4.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[1822055.030820] usb 5-1.2.4.4: Product: Portable
[1822055.030822] usb 5-1.2.4.4: Manufacturer: Seagate
[1822055.030823] usb 5-1.2.4.4: SerialNumber: 00000000
[1822055.032443] usb-storage 5-1.2.4.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[1822055.037447] usb-storage 5-1.2.4.4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 0bc2 pid 2300: 200000
[1822055.037492] scsi host6: usb-storage 5-1.2.4.4:1.0
[1822056.043927] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Portable         0130 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[1822056.047311] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[1822056.048132] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] 4294967295 512-byte logical blocks: (2.20 TB/2.00 TiB)
[1822056.048421] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[1822056.048422] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 2f 08 00 00
[1822056.050658] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] No Caching mode page found
[1822056.050662] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write back
[1822056.067536] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[1822056.067539] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[1822056.067541] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[1822056.067544] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[1822056.067545] print_req_error: 87 callbacks suppressed
[1822056.067547] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdg, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1822056.067550] buffer_io_error: 93 callbacks suppressed
[1822056.067551] Buffer I/O error on dev sdg, logical block 0, async page read
```

Does the LBA info come from the controller? Why is it 0, why 4294967295?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is intersted - I managed to get to he true size by swapping the HDD BIOS chip. Now I can slowly rescue some data with ddrescue - currently at 121kB/s.

Answer (score 0):

Some disks indicate that they're failing their internal self-tests by reporting their size as 0 blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but the
"weird clicking noises" on spinning hard drives
are known as "the click of death".
It's made by the read/write heads touching the
platter(s).
In general, one should immediately power off such a disk, and get professional data recovery service
to recover as much data as possible.
Unless of course, one has backups of the important data of such disk.